# Concentration of substance over time

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The general problem I am trying to solve for is:

- assume you have a magic cup of water, with volume $\mathbf{V}$, that has perfect mixing characteristic (IE: if you put food coloring in it, it would immediate perfectly mix with all the water in the cup)
- The cup is full and has pure water poured into it a flowrate $\mathbf{F}$ and water spills out at the same rate
- Assume a fixed amount of food coloring, $\mathbf{C}$, is added to the cup at $t$=0
- I would like a function to give me the concentration of food coloring as time goes on

The best I came up with is approximating the amount of food coloring over time in discrete:

$\mathbf{C_n}=\mathbf{C_{n-1}}-\mathbf{F}t\frac{\mathbf{C_{n-1}}}{\mathbf{V}}$

I just cannot remember how to put this into the form I need.

Comment: While you were modeling "spilling", did you consider it to mean that the water spilt is only the old, colored water and it is getting replaced by pure water?

Comment: @Ritam_Dasgupta, yes that is exactly what I am trying to model. The concentration should only be decreasing as the old colored water is replaced by pure water.

Comment: @LiamKelly my assumption is that as the uncolored water flows in, it mixes with the colored water that is already there. Also the mixture keeps flowing out at the same rate as the uncolored water flows in. If this is not the case, how do you ensure that water flowing in does not mix with the existing colored water and only concentration that was at $t = 0$ keeps flowing out? Also can you give us a bit more context of how and where you are trying to apply this? Thank you.

Comment: @MathLover yes that is the case and I think you got it, better yet you shouted how I should have structured the solution. Than you!

Comment: you are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty standard problem and can be represented by first order differential equation.

Assume flow rate $F$ is measured in volume per unit of time. As the inflow and outflow rates are same, the volume $V$ remains constant. We add $C$ amount of color at $t = 0$.

At a given point in time if the amount of color in the water is $x$ then,

$ \displaystyle \frac{dx}{dt} = - \frac{x}{V} \cdot F$

$ \displaystyle \frac{1}{x} dx = - \frac{F}{V} dt $

Integrating both sides, $ \displaystyle \ln x = - \frac{F}{V} \cdot t + c_1$ where $c_1$ is a constant.

At $t = 0, x = C$, so $ \ \displaystyle \ln C = c_1$

Hence the equation is, $ \displaystyle \ln \frac{x}{C} = - \frac{F}{V} \cdot t \implies x = C e^{- \frac{F \cdot t}{V}}$

Comment: You'll notice that C is not the concentration, rather the amount of color present initially. Also, why did you assume F to be a constant?

Comment: @Ritam_Dasgupta Yes that is correct. $x$ is also amount of color at time $t$.

Answer (score 1):

You could approach the problem this way. Note that, if $F$ is flow rate of spilling of colored water, then amount of colored water at an instant $t=t_1$ is:
$$V'=V-\int_0^{t_1}F dt$$
Since color is uniformly distributed, amount of color in this much water is:
$$K=\frac {CV'}{V}$$ from the unitary method.
Hence, concentration of food coloring is $$Conc.=\frac KV$$ since total volume remains constant. Hence finally, expression should be:
$$Conc.=\frac {C(V-\int_0^{t_1} F dt)}{V^2}$$

Comment: This is not the right approach. Flow rate is constant. The amount of color going out of the water per unit of time changes continuously. If we consider that substance dissolves immediately and the mixture is homogenous at all points, we look at the rate at which color comes in which is zero here and the rate at which color flows out and then set up the differential equation.

Comment: No, read the comment I posted under OP's question. OP clarified, the question means to say that only colored water will spill, and that too, at a flow rate of F. This colored water will get replaced by only pure water.

Comment: colored water means the mixture at that point and the concentration of color continuously changes and hence the amount of color flowing out continuously changes. The flow rate does not. This is a standard problem.

Comment: It is incorrect to think that the colored water that was at $t = 0$ after $C$ amount of color was mixed to it is flowing out without mixing with the pure water coming in.

Comment: I know what problem you are talking about. The thing is, you have assumed that the water spilt contains both the colored water present before, as well as the water being added. If that had been what OP had asked, your solution would have been correct. But that is not what has been asked, OP said so him/herself. The way you've modeled the problem is surely more accurate, but that's not what OP wants.

Comment: ok let me pose this as a question to OP.